converse of the Picard–Lindelöf theorem
It is well known that if $F(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y)$ are continuous in the open rectangle $R=I\times J$, then for every $(x_0,y_0)\in R$, then there exists a unique function $y(x)$ such that $y(x_0)=y_0$ and $y'(x)=F(x,y(x))$ in an open interval $I'\subset I$.
My question: Does the converse is true? that is, if either $F(x,y)$ or $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y)$ are discontinues in the open rectangle $R=I\times J$, then for every $(x_0,y_0)\in R$, then there is no unique function such that such that $y(x_0)=y_0$ and $y'(x)=F(x,y(x))$ in an interval $I'\subset I$.

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y)$ continuous is only a sufficient condition, but not necessary.

Thanks @Sigma, but I do not understand the connection of your answer to my question. I stated a weaker version of the Picard Theorem. If the conditions of this weaker version do not apply, does it mean that there exist more then one solution of ODE that passes thought the point $(x_0,y_0)$?

No, you could have $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} (x,y)$ not continuous but the uniqueness of the solution still holds.

Thanks @Sigma. Do you have a counter example? Furthermore,  $F(x,y)$ is discontinues, then a unique solution can still exists?

Consider the following: $$\begin{cases}y'(x)=|y(x)| \ y(0)=1\end{cases}$$ Prove that $f(x,y)=|y|$ is locally lipschitz wrt $y$ but its partial derivative $\partial_y f$ is clearly discontinuous. Then, solve the Cauchy problem and check that the uniqueness of the solution is satisfied.

On the other hand, if $F(x,y)$ is not continuous, then the solution could not exists (Peano's theorem)

If you have a multi-phase system, nice inside the phases, nice phase boundaries, but discontinuous at the boundaries, then you can get that solutions end at the boundaries, generalized solutions enter a "sliding mode" which they may or may not exit. One can pose directional conditions on the vector field so that such a stalling at the boundary does not happen (but the interesting cases are those with segments in sliding mode).

Consider the following: $$\begin{cases}y'(x)=|y(x)| \\ y(0)=1\end{cases}$$ Let' prove that $f(x,y)=|y|$ is locally Lipschitz wrt $y$ but its partial derivative $\partial_y f$ is clearly discontinuous.

Locally lipschitz

Let's take $y_1,y_2\in \mathbb{R}$, then $$|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|=\left||y_1|-|y_2|\right|\leq |y_1-y_2|$$ So, with $L=1$, the Lipschitz condition is verified.

Partial derivative

$$\partial_y f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1, & y>0 \\ 0, & y=0 \\ -1, & y<0\end{cases}$$ that it's clearly a discontinuous function.
Although the partial derivative $\partial y f(x,y)$ is not continuous (in $x_0=0$), we can still determine a unique solution to the Cauchy problem.
Set $V$ an open neighborhood of $y_0=1$, then using the separation of the variables tecnique, we have:
$$y'=y \iff \frac{dy}{y}=dx \iff \ln(y)=x+C \iff y=Ce^x$$
By imposing the initial condition, we obtain:
$$y(0)=C=1 \Longrightarrow y(x)=e^x$$
So if $U$ is an open neighborhood of $x_0=0$, then $$\varphi: U \to V, \quad\varphi(x)=e^x$$ is the unique solution to the problem.
This is a counterexample to one of the two possibilities.
On the other hand, if $f(x,y)$ is not continuous, then the solution could not exists.
Try with $$\begin{cases}y'(x)=\frac{y(x)}{x}\\ y(0)=1\end{cases}$$
